# Editing Specific numbers in a .txt file with matlab GUI Using search/replace

Tags: matlab, replace, matlab-guide

I have a bunch of different template .txt files that I want to be accessed by a user in matlab. these templates look like this, but with key differences that I will explain:

```
LOAD BOX  1 SUBJ M1_299633_D295158_JUN19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat1 GROUP 1 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbi (x)
LOAD BOX  2 SUBJ M2_297928_D294277_APR19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat2 GROUP 2 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbi (x)
LOAD BOX  3 SUBJ M3_299632_D295158_JUN19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat3 GROUP 1 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbii (x)
LOAD BOX  4 SUBJ M4_297929_D294277_APR19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat4 GROUP 2 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbii (x)
LOAD BOX  5 SUBJ F5_299621_D295158_JUN19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat5 GROUP 1 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbi (x)
LOAD BOX  6 SUBJ F6_297923_D294277_APR19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat6 GROUP 2 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbi (x)
LOAD BOX  7 SUBJ F7_299626_D295158_JUN19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat7 GROUP 1 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbii (x)
LOAD BOX  8 SUBJ F8_297924_D294277_APR19@1910_Aut_ERROR2 EXPT St(n)_Se(m)_Rat8 GROUP 2 PROGRAM 1908_SIP_EPHYS_ERROR2_St3_TrainWZ_Cbii (x)
```

Each template will have a different SUBJ name, but they all have this basic format. there is a separate template for each experiment and squad. Each experiment will have its own folder, and within each of those will be a folder for each squad. I have helpfully named them accordingly. Here is the path to experiment 2, squad 3:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Experimental_Templates\Experiment_No2\EXP2_SQ3\EXP2_SQ3_Template.txt
```

within a GUI in matlab, I want a user to select an experiment from a drop down list, and than enter the squad number. This will load the correct template into matlab. I have created a GUI already, and added here both the .fig and .m files. The .m file is empty, other than initialization for the ui elements. the files can be found on my github: https://github.com/Rambunctiouslad/Rat_Tracking.

After the correct Template has been loaded, I want to basically do a find and replace. each of those strings ((n), (m), and (x)) will be replaced with input typed by a user into one of the GUI's editable text boxes. (n) is the stage number, so typing 4 into the stage box will replace the (n) with a 4, and so on.

After this is done, I want the original template to remain the same, with the placeholder variables. However, I want the updated file to be saved into a specific folder, in a .mac format. .mac is not for apple computers, it is a proprietary format used by the med-pc program.

I am using MATLAB r2019b.

Comment: i think I could use something like this `var1 = 'Text_template_with_variables ';
user = input('enter correct Variables: ', 's')
new = strrep(var1, 'variables', user)` but I dont know how to load the files correctly.

Comment: I think this question is actually too broad. Have you thought of breaking it down into much smaller problems and solve those individually? For example, make sure you can read one text file first. Then move that code into a function and make the filename a parameter of the function so that you can choose an arbitrary file. Then you continue to expand your program in the same way.

Comment: that's actually exactly what I am doing. I realized it was a bit big. I think I am going to ask some more basic questions first. thank you.